# Troubles with libmongoc-1.0.pc / MongoDB on C

Tags: c, mongodb, bson

I'm trying to connect a C code to my mongoDB database. 
I wrote on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libmongoc-1.0-0 #Everything OK
sudo apt-get install libbson-1.0 #Everything Ok
```

Then, I tried to define bjson.h and mongoc.h using PKG_CONFIG_PATH. In this step, I could find and define correctly bson.h, cause I found libbson-1.0.pc in /usr/lib64/pkgconfig, but I can't find libmongoc-1.0.pc or libmongoc-1.0-0.pc!
So, when I try:

```
gcc read_mongo.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libbson-1.0)
```

Just doesn't work! Cause gcc doesn't found mongoc.h libraries.
I tried searching for mongo.h too on my PC and nothing.

How can I get it? There's something over there am I losing?

Answer (score 0):

as you said, read_mongo.c is looking for (and cannot find) mongoc.h, not bson.h

answer can be found in the tutorial package config.

http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/tutorial.html#pkg-config

your gcc line

```
gcc read_mongo.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libbson-1.0)
----------------------------------------------^
```

required gcc line (include and link against libmongoc rather than libbson)

```
gcc -o read_mongo.c read_mongo.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libmongoc-1.0)
--------------------------------------------------------------^
```